# How can I trigger brace expansion inside a script?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, brace-expansion

I'm writing a script which needs to use the shell's brace expansion, but nothing I've tried works.  For (a contrived) instance, say I have a variable containing the string

```
thing{01..02}
```

and I (obviously) want to expand it to

```
thing01 thing02
```

from inside the script, how can I do that?

(For anyone who assumes this is a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846730/tricky-brace-expansion-in-shell), please read them more carefully.  That question is regarding working from the shell, not a shell script, and doesn't require the ability to expand arbitrary expressions.)

Comment: What have you so far in your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo thing{01,02}

thing01 thing02
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that braceexpand is turned on with `set -o braceexpand`.

Comment: When I wrote it in bash script, I got `set: 2: Illegal option -o braceexpand`

Comment: It seems problem was because I was running it as `sh script` instead of `bash script`. Also added that line in bashrc instead of script.